# How many three digit numbers with increasing digits can be formed from the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$?

Tags: combinatorics

> Suppose we pick 3 numbers $x,y,z \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ and form a 3
>   digit number $xyz$ how many possible combinations numbers can we
>   create such that $x < y < z$. For example $357$ would be one such
>   combination.

I'm struggling with this problem here is what I have so far, we know that $x \leq 6$ otherwise there aren't enough numbers in the list to make an increasing sequence. So we have $6$ choices for the first digit. Now is where I am stuck on what to do next.

Please help.

Comment: Note that you must select three numbers from the set.  In how many ways can they be ordered so that the hundreds digit is less than the tens digit, which, in turn, is less than the units digit?

Comment: $7\choose 3$ maybe?

Comment: How did you obtain $\binom{7}{3}$?

Comment: Let placing a bar after a digit denote that that digit is going to be in the number. Then there are $7$ slots to place a bar (e.g. there is one slot between $1,2$ one between $2,3$ etc) so there are $7$ in total. We wish to place 3 to choose the $3$ digits to make up our number hence there are $7 \choose 3$ total ways to do this.

Comment: Well then there would be $18 \choose 11$? Why is this the case anyway since let's say the number is $678$ but $6+7+8 \neq 8$????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the three digits must be distinct, we must select three of the eight elements in the set $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$.  Once we have selected these digits, there is only one way to order them so that the hundreds digit is less than the tens digit, which, in turn, is less than the units digit.  Thus, the number of ways we can construct a three-digit number $100h + 10t + u$ using the elements in set $S$ in which $h < t < u$ is equal to the number of ways we can select a subset of three elements from a set of eight elements.

Comment: Fantastic explanation that is. You really helped me understand it.

Comment: I am glad I could help.  I hope I did not cause you too much confusion with my comments.

Comment: No I understand it now thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Choose three digits from $12345678$. So ${8 \choose 3} = \frac{8!}{5!3!} = 56$

Comment: How does this account for the ordering constraint?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer They are already in order: you're choosing them from the ordered string $12345678$

Comment: I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: Another way to 'see it' if we stick to the idea of combinations, the number of ways of selecting 3 digits from a set of 8 digits, where the order of the 3 digits does not matter, is $ {8 \choose 3} $. For each of these 3 digit combinations, there is only $1$ way in which the ordering is correct, since the digits are distinct, so $ {8 \choose 3} \times 1 $.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to see it, without (explicit) combinatorics:

Fix the middle number to be $k$, $k=2..7$.  You have $k-1$ choices for $x$ and $8-k$ choices for $z$. This gives
$$
\sum_{k=2}^7 (k-1)(8-k)=56.
$$

Comment: Care to explain, downvoter?

Comment: Sorry mate. You're right. It's my opinion but I find this less intuitive and harder to compute than the good old $\frac{8!} {3!5!}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to proceed.

1. How many ways are there to choose any three numbers from the set. Not all of these are admissible. But for any such trio, there is exactly one way to rearrange their order so that $x < y < z$. How many different trios when, after being reordered, give the same sequence? For instance, $321$ and $132$ both rearrange to $123$.
2. First place $z$. How many ways are there to do so? (*Ans: $z$ can be one of $3,4,5,6,7,8$.*) Then place $y$ (the number of choices depends on $z$), and then place $x$.

I find the first to be nicer.

Comment: $${8\choose 3} \times \frac{1}{3}$$?