# The number of 3-digit numbers formed using the digits in set $S=\left\{0,1,2,3,4,5\right\}$,so that the digits either increase or decrease

Tags: combinatorics

The number of 3-digit numbers formed using the digits in set $S=\left\{0,1,2,3,4,5\right\}$,so that the digits either increase or decrease,is
$(A)24\hspace{1cm}(B)30\hspace{1cm}(C)45\hspace{1cm}(D)56$

---

When the digits decrease,number of 3-digit numbers formed$=\binom{6}{3}$,
when the digits increase,number of 3-digit numbers formed$=\binom{5}{3}$
Total$=30$.Is my method right?Have i done correctly?Is my answer right?I am not confident about it.Thanks.

Comment: is $012$ a number or is a leading zero not allowed?

Comment: In 3 digit numbers,leading zero is not allowed,i think.

Comment: then $30$ sounds fine to me...can you justify what you did?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in case of decreasing digits you can take any 3 out of the string 543210 so that the rest will be in descending order, and there are $\binom 6 3$ ways to do that, in case of increasing digits you can take any 2 out of 12345, which can be done in $\binom 5 2 =\binom 5 3$ number of ways. Thus, the result is $\binom 6 3 + \binom 5 3 = 20 + 10 = 30$. Also, take a look at this [MO question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295559/how-many-three-digit-numbers-with-increasing-digits-can-be-formed-from-the-set?rq=1).

Comment: Did you mean you can take any $\color{red}{3}$ out of $12345$ for the increasing case?

Comment: No, I meant 2. The idea is put the rest of the string in ascending order. Sorry if I did not make it clear. I have edited the answer.