# How many subsequences of size x, with increasing numbers, can be created out of a sequence A, with z consecutive numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

I've been struggling with this problem for a while. Here is what I tried to do so far to find out the formula, if there even is one.

Here is an example to make the question clearer:

`If x = 3 and A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} the answer will be 10. (the possible combinations are: 123, 124, 125, 234, 235, 245, 345)`

So, I tried to define the problem like this: Let there be a binary number a with z digits, where the i-th digit in number a is the i-th number in the sequence z. Now, to calculate the number y of possible subsequences we will need to calculate how many binary numbers a with x digits of 1 are there (where, in the binary number a, a "1" on the i-th position means that the i-th element from the sequence A is in the current subsequence x while a "0" means the opposite). But I don't know how to continue from here.

Also, I've seen this post "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295559/how-many-three-digit-numbers-with-increasing-digits-can-be-formed-from-the-set", but I don't know how I could use any information from there for my problem.

Can someone help, please?

Thank you!

Comment: What is z in your example?

Comment: It is 5. (the number of elements in sequence A) Elements in sequence A are the z numbers in consecutive order.

Comment: Not sure I am following.  Why isn't the answer simply $\binom zx$? That is, just select your $x$ numbers and order them sequentially.

Comment: I don't really know what that notation means... What is it equal to?

Comment: As lulu said, the answer is just $\binom{z}x$, sometimes written ${}_zC_x$, which is equal to 
$$
\frac{z!}{x!(z-x)!}
$$
for exactly the reasons the linked question states.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks!!